# check for integer or float values

Tags: php

I have this

```
$number = 0.5

if (is_float($number))
{
  echo 'float';
}
else
{
  echo 'not float';
}
```

and it echos not float.
what could be the reason
thanks

Comment: The code you posted works fine for me (except you forgot a semicolon after the first line).

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Probably `$number` is actually a string: `"0.5"`.

See [`is_numeric`](http://php.net/is_numeric) instead. The `is_*` family checks against the actual type of the variable. If you only what to know if the variable is a number, regardless of whether it's actually an `int`, a `float` or a `string`, use `is_numeric`.

If you need it to have a non-zero decimal part, you can do:

```
//if we already know $number is numeric...
if ((int) $number == $number) {
    //is an integer
}
```

Comment: if its a string then how would I distinguish between an integer and the float point in the sting?
thanks

Comment: @user I've edit the response in order to address your concerns.

Comment: Casting it to an int wouldn't help if you want to check for floats. Also, you should be using [`intval`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) or [`floatval`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php) to convert a string to a number.

Comment: @Daniel Yes, you can... if it's numeric and it's not an int, then it's a float (it's else branch for the if above). See http://codepad.viper-7.com/yqJ75c As to `intval` et al... it's a micro optimization.

Comment: For additional info, if the number is not numeric ((int) $number == $number) gives a false positive for $number = NULL (or = '') as examples.

Comment: @DanielVandersluis "Also, you should be using intval or floatval to convert a string to a number." — Why?

Answer (score 5):

If you are checking just for the `.(dot)` then you do not need to `typecast` but manipulate it as a string with `[strpos][1]()`.

```
if (strpos($number,'.') !== false) {

    echo 'true';
}else {
    echo 'false';
}
```

Comment: What if there are two dots in the string?

Comment: Still you can check as a string, like `if (strpos($number,'..') !== false) `

Comment: There are functions built for this. Why try to use something else.

Comment: There are functions built for this. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 3):

The **is_numeric()** function checks whether a variable is a number or a numeric string. This function returns true if the variable is a number or a numeric string, otherwise it returns false/nothing.

```
$number = 0.5;
echo is_numeric($number);   //true
```

OR

```
$number = "0.5";
echo is_numeric($number);   //true
```

Read more in:

[How to check if a variable is a float in PHP?](https://stackhowto.com/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-a-float-in-php/)

[How to check if a variable is an Integer in PHP?](https://stackhowto.com/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-an-integer-in-php/)

Answer (score 1):

Artefacto's answer will also convert a `5.0` float number into a `5` integer. If that is bugging you like it was bugging me, I offer the answer of [automatic type conversion](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) via the multiplication operator:

> If either operand is a float, then both operands are evaluated as floats, and the result will be a float. Otherwise, the operands will be interpreted as ints, and the result will also be an int.

```php
$demo = array(
    1, 2, 3, '1', '2', '3', 
    1.0, 2.1, 3.2, '1.0', '2.1', '3.2', 
    -17, '-17', 
    -1.0, -2.2, '-1.0', '-2.2',
    0, '0', -0, '-0',
    0.0, '0.0', -0.0, '-0.0',
);

foreach ($demo as $k => $v) {
    if (is_numeric($v) && is_string($v)) {
        $demo[$k] = 1 * $v;
    }
}

echo "<pre>"; var_dump($demo); echo "</pre>";

array(26) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
  [2]=>
  int(3)
  [3]=>
  int(1)
  [4]=>
  int(2)
  [5]=>
  int(3)
  [6]=>
  float(1)
  [7]=>
  float(2.1)
  [8]=>
  float(3.2)
  [9]=>
  float(1)
  [10]=>
  float(2.1)
  [11]=>
  float(3.2)
  [12]=>
  int(-17)
  [13]=>
  int(-17)
  [14]=>
  float(-1)
  [15]=>
  float(-2.2)
  [16]=>
  float(-1)
  [17]=>
  float(-2.2)
  [18]=>
  int(0)
  [19]=>
  int(0)
  [20]=>
  int(0)
  [21]=>
  int(0)
  [22]=>
  float(0)
  [23]=>
  float(0)
  [24]=>
  float(-0)
  [25]=>
  float(-0)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, using the typecast will allow you to check int and float properly regardless of the machine's locale. However, I could be very wrong...I am not sure if PHP supports decimal locales, such as the comma (,) for certain countries.