# Filter integer with JInput

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

I'm retrieving a value from JInput that must be a integer.

```
$input = new JInput();
$post = $input->getArray($_POST);
$value= $input->$post['value'];
```

Now obviously I can't use is_int() because `$_POST` makes the value a string - usually solved with filter_input(). That leaves me in a slight issue - as I want to reject anything that isn't a integer - not convert it into an integer. Using something along the lines of

```
$value=JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('value', '0', 'INT');
```

forces the string to be a integer. (e.g. inputting 1.2 will then give a $value of 1 etc.). So I'm stuck as to how to achieve this filter. Ideally I'd like to do something along the lines of

```
if(is_int($delete)) {
    //Carry on processing data
} else {
    //Stop function and display a JError
JLog::add("Value is not a integer", JLog::WARNING, 'jerror');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found it on SO under [check for integer or float values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461693/check-for-integer-or-float-values).

Final code used was:

```
$input = new JInput();
$post = $input->getArray($_POST);
$value= $input->$post['value'];
//checks value is numeric and if it is a int
if(is_numeric($value) && (int) $value == $value) {
    //process data
} else {
    JLog::add("Value is not a integer", JLog::WARNING, 'jerror');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use:

```
$input = new JInput;
$value = $input->getInt('value');
```

Comment: This still rounds the values down - e.g. inputting 1.2/1.4 will give $value=1. I can already do that as I said in the question. I just want check if the inputted value is a int - not try and round the values down

Answer (score 0):

```
$input = new JInput;
$email = $input->get('email', '', 'post');
$time = $input->get('time', '', 'post');
$move = $input->get('move', '', 'post');
$idcat = $input->get('idcat', '', 'post');
```